# Hydrostatic pressure term in Navier-Stokes equation for non compressible isothermal flow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

So via divergence theorem we derive cauchy equation,i get it.After that we replacing stress tensor with -P(hydrostatic pressure) + shear stress tensor.Finally  we get this equation in cartesian coordinates./
[image]

But in the beginning we did our assumptions like we work on differantial particle and we used divergence theorem to "jump" from surface to inside of that particle so flux over walls was replaced with stress gradient inside.My question is why is there del(P)/del(x)  and del(P)/del(z) in final equations still exists ? we divided stress into 2 parts and one of them which is hydrostatic part,representing here as P,has only gradient in y direction.gradients in all other directions should be equal to zero.We took care of viscous effects,non-hydrostatic stresses in that laplace term already..

Bonus question:
At the equation (9-57) term 2*mu*del(u)/del(x) is representing sigma(xx) -(-P).How does it make sense multiplying dynamic viscosity with "non perpendicular" velocity gradient ? I mean u is already pointing "x" direction.Its gradient in that direction is nothing to do with shear stress..And still it is multiplied with viscosity..

Comment: Who says P varies only with y?  P is not the hydrostatic pressure.  It is the isotropic part of the stress tensor.

Comment: yeah i got it there was misunderstanding.So its pressure gradient in general which for example in z direction will not build up at all in free falling liquid for example.But what about my second question what the hell is meaning of that term ? Dynamic viscosity multiplied with such gradients like du/dx or dv/dy or dw/dz looks nonsense..

Comment: To understand this, you need to examine the tensorially correct extension of Newton's law of viscosity to 3D.  See Chapter 1 of Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.